# Creating categories in table based on value ranges?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am quite new to Arcgis and I am wondering how I can categorize values in a table based on their distance values. For example, I have a table with INPUT_FID and distance values (ignore everything else). I created a new field and I want to categorize each INPUT_FID based on their distances in that new field (A if distance is less than 200, B if distance is more than 200).

[image]

Comment: You need to use a conditional statement in the field calculator, there are several answer covering that in this site and the arcmap help has lot of exemple including this specific case, if you can't make it work update your question with your specific problem

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166498/how-to-automatically-group-values-in-symbology-based-on-rules. But it has to do with the visual map and not a table, so J.R.'s idea to use the field calculator is probably better. Cheers !

Comment: @LoïcPoncin the question you link is concerned to symbology whereas this question is about populating a new field. Bob, [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/251629/86131) does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @MarceloVilla Yep, I revised my comment :)